# How do I do a sql query inside the .hbs files like we do a for .html using php?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my profile.hbs file I am using express node and MySQL for my database. If I wanted to display the username of my logged in user. Where should I do the query and how. Is it inside the app.js or index.js(it has all my routes), or inside the profile.hbs. ALL the files of my project are in  [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996572/handlebar-is-not-changing-when-it-is-authenticated)

```
{{> header }}
    <div>
   <h2>Profile</h2>
   </div>
   Hi 

   </div> <!--Container-->

{{> footer-end}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You profile.hbs is just a template to create html content from data which it receives.

You can query the Mysql from the route on which you are going to render the profile.hbs like this

```
router.get('/getuser/:userid', function(req, res) {

var userid = req.params.userid;

db.query('SELECT * from users where id = ?', userid, function(error, results, feilds) {
    if (error) {
        console.log("error ocurred while getting user details of " + userid, error);
        res.send({
            "code": 400,
            "failed": "error ocurred"
        });
    } else {
        res.render("edituser",{user:results});
    }
});
```

});

This renders the edituser.hbs file with the json of users.

You can use this in your hbs file like:

```
 <td>{{user.name}}</td>
 <td>{{user.username}}</td>
 <td>{{user.email}}</td>
```

Which would render something like this

```
 <td>Test User</td>
 <td>testuser1</td>
 <td>test@example.com</td>
```